# React native debugger transtions are very slow on windows 10, but very fast on linux ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, debugging, react-native

I have a real device Samsung galaxy core, with 1.5 GB of RAM. I make a test debugging the same app on windows 10, with the debugger on and the transitions and animations are very slow. On Linux Ubuntu 64 bit transitions and animations are very fast. I am debugging by adb reverse. React native debugger is slow if I use it by wi-fi in both OS. I am not able to understand the problem on windows because sometimes work fine and fast with the debugger adb reverse.